# Why JS is appending HTML to iFrame head

Tags: javascript, iframe

The code below is working fine when I execute it in the console, but when it is loaded from the page itself (just before the closing body tag), it is not working.

```
document.getElementById('someid').contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML += `
      <style>h1{display:none;}</style>
    `;
```

I am trying to add a style tag in an iframe on the page.

Comment: You're likely getting an error when you run it in the page itself. Research that error. You are barred from changing the DOM of a document that is not in the same domain as yours.

Comment: If it works when you do it via the console, you're probably just doing it too early. The iframe is not loaded yet when you try to change its contents. Try wrapping this code with `var frame = document.getElem...; frame.addEventListener('load', function(){ /* code */ });`

Comment: _"before the closing body tag"_ this is for making sure elements on the current page are loaded, not ones loaded in a separate frame. If the other page is on the same domain you can use the messaging api ([postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), onmessage) to tell the parent page when its content has been loaded and on that event then do the modification